# Service onCreate() is not being called

Tags: android, android-activity, service, unbind

I have a activty A and after a button click I am starting another activity B in which I am starting a service using `bindService` as below:

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, RadioService.class);
context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

During this the `onCreate()` of the service class is being called. Now when I close the activity B inside `onDestroy()` of B I am stopping the service as below:

```
context.unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

The problem that I am facing is second time if I enter the activity B the service class `onCreate()` is not being called. Why is so that the case? What can be done as  I want the `onCreate()` to be called.

Comment: When you `unbind` the service, the system does not destroy the service. This is reason when `onCreate` is not called since the service is already running when you reenter activity B.

Comment: How can I destroy the service?

Comment: You need to call `stopSelf()` or `stopService()`.

Comment: But I am using `bindService` to start my service not `startService()`. And as far as I am aware `stopSelf()` and `stopService()` will only work if we have started service using `startService()`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can check this [section](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle). `stopService()` does depends on how the service is implemented.

Comment: Is `Service.onDestroy()` being called? By the way, this question is directly related to at least one of your others. They have the same cause, and they should probably be combined.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling `startService()` before `bindService()`.